# How can I combine two lists in Netlogo without getting extra brackets?

Tags: list, netlogo

I've been trying to combine two lists, `angles` and `distance`, into a new list, and I want to do it in a way where `angles`' first element is combined with the first x elements in `distance`, like this:

```
[[45 0.5] [45 1] [45 2] [135 0.5] [135 1] [135 2] etc.
```

My problem is that it looks like this:

```
[[[45 0.5] [45 1] [45 2]] [[135 0.5] [135 1] [135 2]] etc.
```

In other words, it has brackets around each couple of items that have the same element from `angles`.

This is how I got here:

```
    let q 0
  let temp ""
  while [ q < length list1 ]
  [
    let l item q list1
    let t 0
    while [t < 9] [
      let d item t coarse-distance-list
      set temp (word temp "[ " d " " l " ] ")
      set t t + 1
    ]
    set q q + 1
  ]
  set chromosomes temp
```

List1 is angles and list2 is distance. I know I can probably do this in a way more easy and efficient way, but at the moment getting the list right is my first priority of course.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I´m sure the pros here will come up with a smarter solution, but try this:

```
to test

  let list1 (list 45 45 45 135 135 135)
  let list2 (list 0.5 1 2 0.5 1 2)
  let temp range length list1

  let result []

  foreach temp [ i ->
    set result lput ( list ( item i list1 ) ( item i list2  ) ) result

  ]

  show result

end
```

This will return you:

```
observer> test
observer: [[45 0.5] [45 1] [45 2] [135 0.5] [135 1] [135 2]]
```

Comment: Good idea to use an anonymous procedure- `map` is good for this too: `print ( map [ [ l1 l2 ] -> ( list l1 l2 ) ] list1 list2 )`

Comment: That´s even better: less lines of code with same result.